# Call field from another table in select firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a table categories and a documents. I want to create a new document and associate this document with a category already created.

The category table has the title field.

In the document creation form I want to put the categories already created in a select.

I tried doing this in the code below, but I ended up getting the select a key from the category -L0_xe_FIK9QdfTGhBDG for example, but I wanted the category title.

```
var documentosRef = firebase.database().ref('documentos');
    var categoriasRef = firebase.database().ref('categorias');

    var keyDocumento = ""

    function initFirebase(){
        categoriasRef.on('value', function(data) {
            $('#categoria').html('');
            for(categoria in data.val()){
                option = "<option>"+categoria+"</option>"
                $('#categoria').html($('#categoria').html()+option);
            }

        })
    }
```

Structure:

```
{   "categorias": {
    "L0_xe_FIK9QdfTGhBDG": {
      "titulo": "Categorias 1"
    },
    "-L0a0FPFkXkKb3VNFN0c":{
      "titulo": "Categorias 2"
    } 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I just got confused here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let check it out: [JavaScript for/in Statement](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forin.asp)

```
var categorias = data.val();
for(var key in categorias){
    option = "<option>"+categorias[key].titulo +"</option>"
    $('#categoria').html($('#categoria').html()+option);
}
```

Comment: Hmm ... so I end up getting within the select an "undefined" string for all my categories.

Comment: what is your database structure, the data of location `/categorias`?

Comment: you should get the value `categorias[val].titulo`

Comment: I get in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: val is not defined

Comment: should be `categorias[key].titulo`